# Count unique numbers in a line of a matrix

Tags: shell, awk

I have a matrix:

```
   >ACTTT  ASB  0.098
    0   0      1    0   
 0.75   0   0.25    0   
    0   0      0    1   
    0   1      0    0   
    1   0      0    0   
    1   0      0    0   
    0   1      0    0   
    0   1      0    0
```

And I want to count the occurrence of '0's not '0.' in the file per line (while ignoring the header), such that for each line I will get the count as 3,2,3,3,3,3,3. 
I tried echo $line | grep -o 0 | wc -l , but it counts the '0.' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print gsub(/(^|[[:space:]])0([[:space:]]|$)/,"&")}' file
3
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: Using `awk` once per file is definitely better than calling `grep` + `wc` once per line of input.

Comment: Btw, I would like to know if iterating over columns and check if they are `0` is faster than the regex. Probably depending on the length of the line, number of columns..

Comment: I really don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An awk script like the following would work:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN  { ORS = "," }
NR > 1 { s =0
         for( f=1; f<= NF; f++) s+= (($f == 0) ? 1 : 0 )
         print s
       }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`.

The first line configures `,` as Output-Record-Separator, the second block is applied to each line except the header. It loops over the fields and if a field `$f` equals 0: the `?` operator is used to increment the line sum of zeros in `s`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing fist. It seems like your are processing the file line by line in a shell loop. This is pretty slow. You should definitely use awk and process the file in on run. Other answers show how to do that.

Below just a theoretical hint how it can be done with `grep` and `wc`. I'm just focussing on the right regular expression.

---

You could grep for a `0` prefixed with a space or the beginning of the line and followed by space or the end of the line:

```
grep '\(^\|[[:space:]]\)0\([[:space:]]\|$\)' a.txt | wc -l
```

The head command is to skip the header line.

Comment: Nah.. I had the `tail -n +1` before but removed it since the OP seems to process the file line by line... :)

Comment: I suspect that's because the OP doesn't yet know the answer to the question [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)